# How to prove that Pumping lemma can't be used to prove regular languages.

Tags: automata, regular-language

I need a prove that pumping lemma can't be used to prove regular language. Pumping lemma is only used for proving non-regular language, but I need to show that how it can't be used to prove regular languages?

Comment: It seems you need an example of a non-regular language which satisfies the conclusion of the pumping lemma. Does that help?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Yes, it helps alot. Thanks

Comment: If you can’t come up with an example on your own, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Converse_of_lemma_not_true).